# Close div when vimeo video ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vimeo, vimeo-api

I need a website to have a intro video (a full width div over the site/background content). So I made a Div with an iframe video (VIMEO) and a button to skip intro (it closes the div with js click).

But I still need it to automaticly close the div just after the video ends. Is there a way to trig this event when vimeo video ends?

I found a way to this in youtube (with api), but unfortunatelly i Need it to be in vimeo because it's possible hide the controls , logo and everything.

Thank you so much for your attention.

**-- UPDATE (IT WORKS!)-- Thanks for your help!
If someone needs a similar solution, here it is the code: **

```
<div id="videointro">

<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/xxxxxxxxx?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&transparent=0&autoplay=1&sidedock=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" title="Funny Cat Videos For Kids" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" data-ready="true"></iframe>

</div>

<button id="btn"></button>


<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="video.js"></script> 


-- JS --

btn.onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("videointro").style.display='none';
};

// vimeo 

var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

player.on('play', function() {
  console.log('Played the video');
});

player.getVideoTitle().then(function(title) {
  console.log('title:', title);
});

player.on('ended', function() {
    console.log('the end');
    player.destroy();
});
```

Comment: Read the docs provided, they will help you further: https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/reference#get-the-ended-state-of-a-video. Google it's a magical thing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but the point is that I'm new to JS.. I still struggle with things that seems simple, but I will try! I've googled some solutions and also searched here in stack, but most are not working!

Comment: Okay, post your code and what you've tried, from there on people will further help you when you're stuck.

Comment: Post your code for the Skip Intro, you can probably reuse the same functionality in `player.getEnded().then(function(ended) {
  // 'ended' indicates whether the video has ended
});`

Comment: Hey, @disinfor, I have update my post with the code. But my skip intro is not working :(

Comment: @prettyInPink, I've just updated my question with my code. But it's not working.

Comment: @Jay it's probably not working because you are doing this: `btn.onclick = function ()....` but nowhere are you defining what the `btn` variable is.

Comment: Hey, thank you once again for your answer and kindness. Is btn an id or <button> ?

Will this hide a div with id="videointro":

HTML
<button>skip intro</button>  

JS 
btn.onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("videointro").style.display='none';
};

Comment: Oh, I got it!

<button id="btn">skip button</button>

btn was an id!  now the skip button is working fine! 

But the div with iframe vimeo video is still not closing when video ends ...

Comment: Because the id is `intro` not `videointro`

Comment: You could also just use `player.destroy()` in the `getEnded` function instead of the `document.getElement....` Also, anytime you are reusing the same `document.getElementById`, you should assign it to a variable.

Comment: Hey, dude. Thank you so much. I think it is almost there. The console logs shows me that  the function is running fine, but the problem is that it's being executed at the beginning of the video, not at the end.  I will update my question with a picture of the log for you to see it. Thank you so much for your attention and kindness.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIVuE.png   this picture shows the log.

Comment: It worked, dude, with this player.on('ended', function() {  instead of  player.getEnded().then(function(ended) { !

Comment: You should copy the working code into an answer and revert the question back to the non-working code. That will stop this from getting closed and you'll actually be helping others in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

**If someone needs a similar solution, here goes the code:**

```
<div id="videointro">

<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/xxxxxxxxx?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&transparent=0&autoplay=1&sidedock=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" title="Funny Cat Videos For Kids" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" data-ready="true"></iframe>

</div>

<button id="btn"></button>


<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="video.js"></script> 


-- JS --

btn.onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("videointro").style.display='none';
};

// vimeo 

var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

player.on('play', function() {
  console.log('Played the video');
});

player.getVideoTitle().then(function(title) {
  console.log('title:', title);
});

player.on('ended', function() {
    console.log('the end');
    player.destroy();
});
```